# MariaDB, How to copy existing records using insert?

Tags: sql, insert, mariadb, copy

I have a lot of existing records which I want to copy using an **INSERT**, for example if I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `threats` WHERE biDataset=9;
```

The common key is **biDataset**, the primary key in this table is **biPK** which is auto incremented on each insert.  Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `threats` (
      `biPK` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary key',
      `biDataset` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID of dataset',
      `jsonParams` LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON object containing all parameters' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin',
      `txtTrainee` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Trainee host name (NULL if not applicable)' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      PRIMARY KEY (`biPK`) USING BTREE,
      UNIQUE INDEX `dataset and json` (`biDataset`, `jsonParams`) USING HASH,
      INDEX `datasetIdx` (`biDataset`) USING BTREE,
      INDEX `jsonIdx` (`jsonParams`(768)) USING BTREE
)
COMMENT='Table of datasets'
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=174;
```

What I want to do is copy all the records that exist where **biDataset** is 9, creating new records, I need to be able to specify the new **biDataset** too, 15 to use for all copies instead of 9.

I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO `threats` (biDataset, txtTrainee, jsonParams)
    SELECT 15, NULL, jsonParams FROM `threats` WHERE biDataset=9;
```

This results in:

```
SQL Error (1364): Field 'DB_ROW_HASH_1' doesn't have a default value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to modify the table structure to:

```
CREATE TABLE `threats` (
      `biPK` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary key',
      `biDataset` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ID of dataset',
      `jsonParams` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'JSON object containing all parameters' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin',
      `txtTrainee` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Trainee host name (NULL if not applicable)' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      PRIMARY KEY (`biPK`) USING BTREE,
      UNIQUE INDEX `dataset and json` (`biDataset`, `jsonParams`) USING HASH,
      INDEX `datasetIdx` (`biDataset`) USING BTREE,
      INDEX `jsonIdx` (`jsonParams`(768)) USING BTREE
)
COMMENT='Table of datasets'
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=174
;
```

Comment: For those who don't want to waste their time playing spot-the-difference, two columns that were previously designated 'NOT NULL' were changed to be nullable. This seems to be only required for columns involved in a 'USING HASH' index.

Answer (score 1):

This is bug of mariadb, and it is still unresolved...

Checkout: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22756

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).